# Data scraping: How to read all table content from multiple pages (using next page)?

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

I am trying to scrape data from web page with (**UiPath**) Data Scraping wizard.
The table is well structured and on first click suggest to read whole table.

I want all the data, so I set MaxNumberOfResults to 0.

[ExtractData setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycmyN.jpg)

Next button was properly marked and it does work except last page. 
The issue is that the procedure break down due to looking for next button, because it exist on the page, but it is not possible to push it, so it expect that there are more pages.

I tested the "Next" button with "Element Exist" and it is all the time True even on last page.

[Element exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0a0O.jpg)

Last page buttons look like this [last page buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXH3z.jpg)

Any suggestion or similar experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the UiExplorer, some buttons have extra fields that aren't always used in the selector, there could be additional fields that could be used to differentiate between the working Next button and the greyed out Next button.

Or perhaps you could use the `Get Attribute` activity, if the Next button has a field such as `enabled` which could return true or false depending on whether there is another page.

Comment: Good idea Conor, thanks. 
I checked the HTML code and there is a difference in aria-disabled="true" ("false"). 
Unfortunately, Get Attribute do not return anything and UiExplorer do not see that attribute.

Comment: Does the URL change as you press Next could you read the URL each time you press next and if it doesn't change then you know that you have reached the end.

Comment: Oh, I missed the context w/ Get Attribute. 
aria-disabled is the value to get. Now it works! (I mean to get the attribute, not the whole process :))